# Clamp for rope to make in a hoop?

Tags: repair, product-recommendation

Here's a bit of an odd one for you. I have a length of rope I need to put one end into a hoop to support the weight of a boxing bag. The hoop cannot be "tied" though. I somehow need something like this: [image]

but stronger I think. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Something like this: but smaller :)

[image]

Comment: Why can't the loop be tied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make an eye splice

[image: eye splice]

Instructions on [animatedknots.com](http://www.animatedknots.com/splice/index.php) and many other places.

Comment: +1 Splices like this, and even the bowline and figure 8 (or Flemish bend) are valuable tools that too few people seem to know anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you need something that's easily removable / adjustable, there's the [Figure 9](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HN6CWY) ... they make them in different sizes ... I have a few for dealing with tying down smaller cords.

Answer (score 2):

Yep ! definitely something like this I've used it myself. [Here](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=rope+clamp&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=11980012904370844544&ei=9lYDTbijNMH58AaSk6jqAg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CIMBEPMCMAU#) is a screenshot of what it looks like, you should be able to pick this up at any home improvement store. You make your loop and run the incoming and outgoing strands of rope on in the middle of the clamp and then use a hammer or vice to clamp the edges down on the rope. I was pulling heavier loads so I used two of them just for the sake of paraonia but it works like a charm and only cost a dollar or two.